# counter with IP block via files - PHP

Tags: php

I tried to write a counter for visits of my page, which only counts each IP once per day.
I transcribed a found code to understand how it works and to implement some other features later.
Unfortunately my new code doesn't work.

Code I made from it:

```
<?php
$timeReset = 86400; //24h
$ipPath = "ipsafe.txt";
$countPath = "counts.txt";
$timePath = "time.txt";

$ip = $REMOTE_ADDR;
$time = time();
$resetTime = $time+$timeReset;

$timeFile = fopen($timePath, "r+");
$timeData = fread($timeFile, filesize($timePath));
//if resetTime is passed -> Reset
if($time >= $timeData) {
    //clear ipSafe
    $ipFile1 = fopen($ipPath, "w+"); 
    fclose($ipFile);
    //set new resetTime
    rewind($timeData);
    fwrite ($timeData, $resetTime);
}
fclose($timeFile);

//creat IP-List
$ipData = file($ipPath);
while (list ($line_num, $line) = each ($ipData)) {
    $digits = explode(",",$line);
}
//if IP was not saved in last timeframe
if(!in_array($ip, $digits))
{
    //write new IP
    $ipFile2=fopen($ipPath, "a+");
    @flock($ipFile1,2);
    fwrite($ipFile2, "$ip".",");
    @flock($ipFile1,3);
    fclose($ipFile2);
    //increment counter
    $countFile = fopen($countPath,"r+");
    $countData = fread($countFile, filesize($countPath);
    rewind($countFile);
    $countData++;
    fwrite($countFile, $countData);
    fclose($countFile);
}
?>
```

with the following questions:

- what's wrong with my code?
- flock is used to manage the access to the files, but why shall I use different names for the same file?

Thanks for your suggestions.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for being so unspecific in explaining the problem. After integrating a debugger, I changed "REMOTE_ADDR" to "$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']" so I fixed 1 error. Now i got the following problems:

```
Warning: fopen(time.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../counter.php on line 15
```

But the file is in the same directory as counter.php - of course the fread and filesize failed too

```
Warning: fopen(ipsafe.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in .../counter.php on line 20
```

The file doesn't exist yet, but I thought "fopen($ipPath, "w+");" creats it if it doesn't exist.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function fb() in .../counter.php on line 26
```

Doesn't "fb($timeFile);" send the value to firePHP?

Comment: _What's wrong with my code?_ .. hmm .. so how specific do you want use to be ;)

Comment: ip != user(visitor), game over

Comment: @CadanoX Ok, seriously now, what is the problem you are experiencing with this code?

Comment: You have to learn how to debug!

Comment: I hope someone could answer, after i specified my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not doing a full code review (which would result in an almost full rewrite of your code), here are the things I would recommend changing to fix your listed issues:

The following line uses `$REMOTE_ADDR`, which is undefined.

```
$ip = $REMOTE_ADDR;
```

You most likely meant to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (which you confirmed with your edit), so the line should read:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

You state you're receiving an error attempting to open the `time.txt` file: "No such file or directory". You also say that the file exists in the same directory as `counter.php` - and yet you're still receiving this error. This can mean one of two things; the first, the file doesn't exist and you're mistaken; the second, your counter.php file is in a different directory than whatever script is executing it - this would mean that the `time.txt` file would need to be in the directory of the executing script. I would recommend two things for this.

The first, if the file actually exists, use an absolute path for it:

```
$timePath = '/path/to/your/files/time.txt';
```

The second, verify if the file exists (in code) and if not, create it. `fopen()` with `r`/`r+` flags *does not* create a file if it doesn't exist, so this needs to be manual. Try changing the code to the following:

```
if (!file_exists($timePath)) touch($timePath);
$timeFile = fopen($timePath, 'r+');
if ($timeFile) {
    // the rest of your code
}
```

You say you're receiving an error when opening the `ipsafe.txt` file: "Permission denied". This is a fun one; Though the line numbers don't match with your sample code, I believe these are the lines in question:

```
//clear ipSafe
$ipFile1 = fopen($ipPath, "w+"); 
fclose($ipFile);
```

The first issue is that you never use `$ipFile1` in your code (except erroneously locking/unlocking it; see below for that info). The second is that you call `fclose($ipFile);`. There is no handle named `$ipFile`! You can remove these lines of code!

You attempt to `rewind` the file pointer in your `time.txt` file to write the new time, however, you're using the value you read-in from the file `$timeData` - not the file itself `$timeFile`. Update the lines to the following:

```
rewind($timeFile);
fwrite($timeFile, $resetTime);
```

You read in the file `ipsafe.txt`, again, to look through the full list of IP addresses - if the current user's IP isn't in it, you add it. This may be a logic issue, but you're *only* checking the IP addresses of the last line of the file - but you still iterate through every line of the item. Per the comment in the code: `//if IP was not saved in last timeframe`, I'm going to assume that this is what you're intending to do - but just in case - I would recommend moving the full `if`-statement block that appears below the loop to inside the loop.

Here's the fun block:

```
//write new IP
$ipFile2=fopen($ipPath, "a+");
@flock($ipFile1,2);
fwrite($ipFile2, "$ip".",");
@flock($ipFile1,3);
fclose($ipFile2);
```

You open the file into `$ipFile2` (**2**), then you lock a completely different file `$ipFile1` (**1**), write to **2**, unlock **1**, and then close **2**. I think that you're intentions were to lock/unlock **2**, which would make perfect sense here, so I'd recommend changing `$ipFile1` to `$ipFile2` in those lines.

That should about do it (potentially). After everything, the code should resemble something similar to:

```
<?php
$timeReset = 86400; //24h
$ipPath = "ipsafe.txt";
$countPath = "counts.txt";
$timePath = "time.txt";

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$time = time();
$resetTime = $time+$timeReset;

if (!file_exists($timePath)) touch($timePath);
$timeFile = fopen($timePath, "r+");
if ($timeFile) {
    $timeData = fread($timeFile, filesize($timePath));
    //if resetTime is passed -> Reset
    if($time >= $timeData) {
        //set new resetTime
        rewind($timeFile);
        fwrite ($timeFile, $resetTime);
    }
    fclose($timeFile);

    //creat IP-List
    $ipData = file($ipPath);
    while (list ($line_num, $line) = each ($ipData)) {
        $digits = explode(",",$line);
    }
    //if IP was not saved in last timeframe
    if(!in_array($ip, $digits)) {
        //write new IP
        $ipFile2=fopen($ipPath, "a+");
        @flock($ipFile2, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($ipFile2, "$ip".",");
        @flock($ipFile2, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($ipFile2);
        //increment counter
        if (!file_exists($countPath)) touch($countPath);
        $countFile = fopen($countPath,"r+");
        if ($countFile) {
            $countData = fread($countFile, filesize($countPath);
            if (empty($countData)) $countData = 0; // initialize the counter to '0' if it hasn't been set
            rewind($countFile);
            $countData++;
            fwrite($countFile, $countData);
            fclose($countFile);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now, I also have one additional logic issue regarding your `$resetTime` variable. Ideally, incrementing by a single day is to add 24 hours to a given timestamp (24 hours = 86400 seconds). However, daylight savings time will break this. Instead of doing the following:

```
$resetTime = time() + 86400;
```

Try going a different route (if you're worried about this, that is):

```
$resetTime = strtotime('+1 day');
```